# Guard in Angular stuck in loop

Tags: angular, routes, guard

as title says I'm stuck in loop as I was working with routing and guards.
My plan was activate LogedInGuard if user il logged in, so that he cannot see login form if token exists. If I go on that route, console.log is saying "logedin guard return false" all over again. Here's my routing code:

```
{ 
    path: 'admin', 
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [LogedInGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', 
      component: AdminLoginComponent, 
      pathMatch: 'full',
      canActivate: [LogedInGuard],
      },
      { 
        path: 'dashboard', 
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: AdminDashboardComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', component: AdminNewsListComponent},
          { path: 'add-news/:id', component: AdminAddNewsComponent},
          { path: 'add-news', component: AdminAddNewsComponent},
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

and guard code:

```
@Injectable()
export class LogedInGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AdminService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(){
    if(this.auth.isAuthenticated()){
      console.log("logedin guard return false");
      this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard'])
      return false;
    }
    console.log("logedin guard return true");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have a loop because once you navigate to any path starting with `/admin` your `LogedInGuard` is called. In this guard you navigate to a route starting with `/admin`, which will result in another call to `LogedInGuard`.
In order to prevent getting stuck in a loop you should remove `LogedInGuard` from your parent route config (for `/admin`):

```
{ 
    path: 'admin', 
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', 
      component: AdminLoginComponent, 
      pathMatch: 'full',
      canActivate: [LogedInGuard],
      },
      { 
        path: 'dashboard', 
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: AdminDashboardComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', component: AdminNewsListComponent},
          { path: 'add-news/:id', component: AdminAddNewsComponent},
          { path: 'add-news', component: AdminAddNewsComponent},
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```